# Etymology of "ежу понятно"

Tags: этимология

Откуда пошло выражение "ежу понятно"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Это цитата из стихотворения В. В. Маяковского «Сказка о Пете, толстом ребенке, и о Симе, который тонкий» (1925):

Ясно даже и ежу —

Этот Петя был буржуй.

Строки Маяковского настолько врезались в память каждому, кто прочел их в детстве, что, по статистике Google, в 1190 случаях говорящие употребляют это выражение именно в его исходной форме (ясно даже и ежу).

Есть и другая версия, в СССР существовала сеть интернатов для одаренных детей — например, физ.-мат. интернаты (Москва, Новосибирск, Санкт-Петербург, Киев…). В них набирали подростков, которым осталось учиться два года (классы А, Б, В, Г, Д, Е) или один год (классы **Е, Ж, И**). Учеников одногодичного потока так и называли — "ежи", между ними и учениками двухгодичного потока всегда существовали трения и конкуренция. За год обучения в интернате по нестандартной программе ученик двухгодичного потока сильно опережал только что поступивших в интернат "ежей", поэтому в начале учебного года выражение "ежу понятно" было очень актуально.

Взято [отсюда](http://www.gramma.ru/RUS/?id=14.77).

Comment: Вторая версия (от г-на Аниськина по приведённой ссылке), по-моему, сильно протянута за уши. В Питерском интернате (ФМШ 45) в 80-е годы не было одногодичных классов (е, ж, и). Был один 3-х годичный класс А и четыре 2-х годичных Б, В, Г, Д. Так что ежей не получалось. :-)